# How to make word-wrap to spare on spaces

Tags: html, css

I need word-wrap to spare text on spaces like :

This is my
text

and now it spares like

This is my t
ext

My code is

```
<style>
    #grid {word-wrap: break-word ;}
    #grid {white-space: pre-wrap ;}
</style>

<table id="grid"></table>
```

Table is filled with some random text by jQuery, but I don't think it is important now.

full code:

```
<style>

A {

    color: #000;

}



html, body {

    height: 95%;

}

    #grid {word-wrap: break-word ;}
    #grid {white-space: pre-wrap ;}
```

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

infoName = '@Model.infoName';

$('#grid').jqGrid({

    hidegrid: false,

    url: "/Home/GetInfo/" + @Model.infoIdOut, page: 1,

    datatype: 'json',

    jsonReader: {

        repeatitems: false

   },

    mtype: 'GET',

    afterInsertRow: function (rowid, aData) {



    },

    colNames: ['infoid', infoName],

    colModel: [

        { name: 'infoId', index: 'infoId',  hidden: true, sortable: false },

        { name: 'infoText',  align: 'left', sortable: false, hidden: false}

    ],

    height: '100%',

    rowNum: 1,

    viewrecords: true,

    subGridOptions: {

        openicon: "ui-helper-hidden"

    },

    loadComplete: function () {

        gridId = ("grid");

        gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();

        gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);



        gridId = "tree";

        gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

        $('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);

    }

});

$('#tree').jqGrid({

    url: '/Home/infoTree/',

    mtype: 'GET',



    treeGrid: true,

    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',

    ExpandColumn: 'infoName',

    ExpandColClick: true,

    treedatatype: 'json',

    datatype: 'json',

    colNames: ['infoId', 'infoName'],

    colModel: [

                { name: 'infoId', index: 'infoId', hidden: true, sortable: false },

                { name: 'infoName', index: 'infoName', hidden: false, sortable: false }

    ],

    onSelectRow: function (ids) {

        if (ids != null) {

            data = jQuery('#tree').getRowData(ids);

            jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({ url: "/Home/GetInfo/" + ids })

                .trigger('reloadGrid');

        }

    },

    caption: ''

});



$("#grid").jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid");



gridId = "grid";

gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();

$('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);



gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

$('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);



gridId = "tree";

gridWidth = $('#gbox_' + gridId).parent().width();



$('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridWidth);



gridHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

$('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridHeight);



$('#' + gridId).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")

    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")

    .hide();



    <div class="span3" style="font-size: 12.0pt">

    <div class="specialtree" style="height:100%; width: 100%">

        <table id="tree" style="height:100%; width: 100%"></table>

    </div>
```

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span9">

        <table id="grid" style="height:100%; width: 100%"></table>

    </div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “spare on spaces”? Show some real example and specify exactly what is the thing in the rendering you would like to change and how.

Comment: Don't use `word-wrap` at all and that will fix the issue

Comment: if I don't use word-wrap all my text goes as one line, no matter if there is free space for it or not..

Comment: There are numerous potential causes - we need to see more code to help you find the issue.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing on?

Comment: on ie11, I know I should add some tags for others

Comment: tables are not confined to the same rules of css exactly as you would expect them to be. Though some argue they follow the exact same rules there are exceptions and defaults on how they act. The part that will wrap is in the TD. The table only creates bounds for the TD / TR elements. When you move forward you will want to put a limit on those and removing wordwrap will get rid of the way this acts.